# Exception while accessing a List of List of DateTime objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, datatable

I have a `List<List<DateTime>>`, which I'm trying to set via a for loop, but I get the `IndexOutOfRangeException`, tried hard but am not able to eliminate that exception.

The code is as follows:

```
protected void btnTimeStamp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string serviceName = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
            List<string> serviceNameArray = new List<string>();
            for (int x = 1; x <= 40; x++)
            {
                if (x < 10)
                {
                    serviceNameArray.Add(@"\\Server10" + x + @"\WebSite" + "\\" + serviceName);
                }
                else
                {
                    serviceNameArray.Add(@"\\Server1" + x + @"\WebSite" + "\\" + serviceName);
                }
            }
            List<List<string>> ultimateList = new List<List<string>>();
            List<int> numList = new List<int>();
            //Call the Search method

            for (int y = 0; y < 40; y++)
            {
                ultimateList.Add(Search(serviceNameArray[y]));
            }
            for (int z = 0; z < 40; z++)
            {
                numList.Add(ultimateList[z].Count);
            }
            List<List<DateTime>> listOfDateTimes = new List<List<DateTime>>();
            for(int xx=0;xx<40;xx++)
               {
                for(int yy=0;yy<numList[xx];yy++)
                {
                **listOfDateTimes[xx].Add(File.GetLastWriteTime(ultimateList[xx][yy]));//Index out of range exception on this line of code**
                }
            }
           //Some more code to create a dynamic data table and stuffs
}

public List<string> Search(string path)
        {
            List<string> listOfFiles = new List<string>();
            try
            {
                foreach (string files in Directory.GetFiles(path))
                {
                    listOfFiles.Add(files);
                }
                foreach (string dirs in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
                {
                    listOfFiles.AddRange(Search(dirs));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }
            return listOfFiles;

        }
```

The summary of code is such that I need to get the file names and their last write time for some 40 shared locations and bind them in a grid.

Hence I have been using `List<List<string>>` and `List<List<DateTime>>`.

Experts please help.

Regards

ANurag

Comment: Debug your code, and check the value of `xx` and `yy`, then make sure `xx` is always less than `listOfDateTimes.Count` and `ultimateList.Count`, and that `yy` is always less than `ultimateList[xx].Count`.

Comment: @dcastro I have debugged it a number of times. xx and yy values are pretty ok.

Comment: This generally happens in boundary cases. Check the last pass of loop execution.

Comment: Why don't you encapsulate those strings, ints and dates into a class with a meaningful name, and add a "collection" class (again with a meaningful name)? No one will be able to understand your later, when maintenance has to be done!

Comment: @BernhardHiller once the code works. I have plans to make the workable code beautiful by refactoring, encapsulation and stuffs. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listOfDateTimes` is empty, you forgot to insert the nested lists.

```
List<List<DateTime>> listOfDateTimes = new List<List<DateTime>>();
for(int xx=0;xx<40;xx++)
{
    listOfDateTimes.Add(new List<DateTime>());
    for(int yy=0;yy<numList[xx];yy++)
    {
        listOfDateTimes[xx].Add(File.GetLastWriteTime(ultimateList[xx][yy]));
    }
}
```

Or

```
List<List<DateTime>> listOfDateTimes = Enumerable.Range(0, 40)
                                                 .Select(i => new List<DateTime>())
                                                 .ToList();
```

Comment: @dcastro...Thank you for looking into my question..Let me try your solution.

Comment: @dcastro..works perfectly..Tanks a ton. Btw I need to put these 40 lists inside different columns in a gridview. How should I proceed? I have created a DataTable with 40 columns and then am trying to do:for (int k = 0; k <=40; k++)
            {
                for (int d = 0; d < numList[k]; d++)
                {
                    dtForGridView.Rows.Add(ultimateList[d][k], listOfDateTimes[k]);
                }
                } Throws me a weird exception.Can you shed some light on this?

Comment: @Anurag If this question has been answered and you have a new question, you should mark one of the answers as accepted and open a new question. I wouldn't be able to answer your new question, I don't know much about data binding.

Answer (score 1):

You are not initializing the inner list, initialize the inner list using the following line:

```
listOfDateTimes.Add(new List<DateTime>());
```

related code section:

```
List<List<DateTime>> listOfDateTimes = new List<List<DateTime>>();           

for(int xx=0;xx<40;xx++)
{
    listOfDateTimes.Add(new List<DateTime>());
    for(int yy=0;yy<numList[xx];yy++)
    {
        listOfDateTimes[xx].Add(File.GetLastWriteTime(ultimateList[xx][yy]));
    }
}
```

and if the exception still exists the problem seems to be related with `ultimateList`; check the maximum index of `ultimateList`.

Comment: Shouldn't he be getting a `NullReferenceException` then?

Comment: no, because first you are accessing an object in a list and the first check is whether the index is out of range. This is different than having the list initialized and having a null value in the list.

Comment: @daryal Nope it doesn't work. Again IndexOutOfRangeException.

Comment: @dcastro the following also produces indexoutofrangeexception List<List<int>> temp = new List<List<int>>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                temp[i][0] = 3;
            }

Comment: @darya `listOfDateTimes[xx]= new List<DateTime>();` will also produce an IOR exception. You should be doing `listOfDateTimes.Add(new List<DateTime>());` instead.

Comment: `listOfDateTimes` *is* being initialized in the first line of the code snippet you cut the from question. It's legal to call `Add` on it.